# Proving lower bound for an integral

Tags: definite-integrals, upper-lower-bounds, measurable-functions, integral-inequality

> **Prop.** Let $f\colon [0,1]\times[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a symmetric measurable function. Then we have $$ \iiint\limits_{[0,1]^3} \prod_{\mathrm{cycl}}f(x,y) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z +\iiint\limits_{[0,1]^3} \prod_{\mathrm{cycl}}(1-f(x,y))\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z \geq \frac{1}{4} $$

After expanding a bit, the $f(x,y)f(y,z)f(z,x)$ term cancels, and what remains is the following claim:

$$ \iiint\limits_{[0,1]^3} (1-f(x,y)-f(y,z)-f(z,x) +f(x,y)f(y,z)+f(y,z)f(z,x)+f(z,x)f(xy)) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z \geq \frac{1}{4} $$

By linearity, we get:

$$ 1-3\iint\limits_{[0,1]^2}f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y+3\iiint\limits_{[0,1]^3}f(x,y)f(y,z) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z \geq \frac{1}{4}$$

or

$$ \frac{1}{4}+\iiint\limits_{[0,1]^3}f(x,y)f(y,z) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z \geq \iint\limits_{[0,1]^2}f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y $$

or

$$ \iiint\limits_{[0,1]^3}f(x,y)(1-f(y,z))\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z \leq \frac{1}{4} $$

Any ideas on how to prove this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have:
$$\begin{align} 
I&:=\iiint\limits_{[0,1]^3} (1-\underbrace{(f(x,y)+f(y,z)+f(z,x))}_{\text{symmetry} \Longrightarrow3f(x,z)} +\underbrace{(f(x,y)f(y,z)+f(y,z)f(z,x)+f(z,x)f(xy))}_{\text{symmetry} \Longrightarrow3f(z,x)f(y,z)}) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z \\
&=\iiint\limits_{[0,1]^3} (1-3f(x,y)+3f(x,y)f(y,z)) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z  \hspace{1cm} \text{symetry of }(x,y,z) \text{ over }[0,1]^3\\
&=\iiint\limits_{[0,1]^3} 1dxdydz -3\iiint\limits_{[0,1]^3} f(x,y) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z  +3\iiint\limits_{[0,1]^3} (f(x,y)f(y,z) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z 
\end{align}$$
The first integral is equal to
$$I_1:=\int\limits_{[0,1]} 1dy$$
For the second integral:
$$I_2:=\iiint\limits_{[0,1]^3} f(x,y) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z=\iint\limits_{[0,1]^2} f(x,y) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \int_{[0,1]}\left(\int\limits_{[0,1]} f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\right)dy$$
For the second integral, as the function $f$ is symmetric
$$\begin{align}
I_3 &:=\iiint\limits_{[0,1]^3} f(x,y)f(y,z) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z \\
&=\int_{[0,1]}\left(\iint\limits_{[0,1]^2} f(x,y)f(z,y) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}z\right)dy  \hspace{0.5cm}\text{as the function $f$ is symmetric, $f(y,z)=f(z,y)$}\\
&=\int_{[0,1]}\left(\int\limits_{0\le z\le 1}f(z,y)\left(\int_{0\le x\le 1}  f(x,y)dx \right) \mathrm{d}z\right)dy\\
&=\int_{[0,1]}\left(\left(\int_{0\le x\le 1} f(x,y)dx\right)\left(\int_{0\le z\le 1}f(z,y) dz\right)\right)dy\\
&=\int_{[0,1]}\left(\int\limits_{[0,1]^2} f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\right)^2dy
\end{align}$$

Finally,
$$\begin{align}
I &= I_1 - 3I_1 +3I_2 \\
&=  \int_{[0,1]}\left(1 -3\left(\int\limits_{[0,1]^2} f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\right)  +3\left(\int\limits_{[0,1]^2} f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\right)^2\right)   dy\\
&=  \int_{[0,1]}\left(\frac{1}{4} +3\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\int\limits_{[0,1]^2} f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\right)^2\right)   dy  \ge \int_{[0,1]}\left(\frac{1}{4} \right) = \frac{1}{4}   dy
\end{align}$$
The equality occurs iff the function $f(x,y)$ satisfies
$$\int_{0\le x\le 1}f(x,y)dx = \frac{1}{2}  \hspace{1cm} \text{for all $y\in [0,1]$}$$

Comment: Thank you! In $I_3$, why exactly will be $\iint\limits_{[0,1]^2}f(x,y)f(y,z) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}z = \left(\int_0^1 f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\right)^2$?

Comment: @sicmath I added more details, perhaps it may help.

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly clear now. Thanks for the answer again!